# MySQL Trigger creation issue

Tags: mysql, triggers

Getting this error when trying to create the trigger- #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE orderCount INT;
 SET orderCount = (SELECT COUNT(Order_No) FROM `order' at line 5

```
delimiter /

CREATE TRIGGER CountOrders

BEFORE INSERT ON order 

DECLARE orderCount INT;

SET orderCount = (SELECT COUNT(Order_No) FROM `order` WHERE Outlet = 1 AND
complete ='FALSE');       
BEGIN

IF orderCount > 3
THEN SIGNAL 'To many orders pending'

END;
/

delimiter ;
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have couple of issues in the trigger. Here is one with modification.
The `declare` part should be after `begin` , and order is a reserved word so need to wrap in backticks

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER CountOrders BEFORE INSERT ON `order` 
for each row
begin
 DECLARE orderCount INT;
 SELECT COUNT(Order_No) into orderCount FROM `order` 
 WHERE Outlet = 1 AND complete ='FALSE' ; 
 IF orderCount > 3 then
   SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'To many orders pending';
 end if;
end ;//

delimiter ;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html

Comment: Also, I was wondering how would you replace Outlet = 1 with input from the insert statement??

Comment: Did not get could you please explain a bit ?

Comment: Outlet number could vary depending on what outlet the order has been placed at. I substituted Outlet = 1 when it could have been Outlet = 2 ect. Is it possible to select a different outlet as at the moment the trigger will only run if outlet 1 has to many orders.